# static analysis of Android application

Tags: java, android, static-analysis

If I want to develop static analysis for Android applications, what entrypoints should I use? There are two options I have in mind:

1. Use `ActivityThread.main()` from `./frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java` (or `Looper.loop()` from `./frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Looper.java`) as entry
2. Use a made-up `main()` which contains only code that calls `onCreate()`, `onPause()`, `onResume()`, and etc.

Are there valid choices? Is there other choice that you think more fit?

Comment: Hello dacongy, I am a totally newbie to static analysis of Android apps, could you please share any links/pdfs that should be referred to ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second approach seems more reasonable but is still incomplete. How to model the event handlers (typically `onXXX()`) is a difficult problem. A formalism should be provided to describe GUI, event-driven programs. Answer would be updated when more details are gathered.